# How to clean rubber and plastic parts with sticky, thick teflon-based lube stains?

Tags: lubricant, cleaning

I once lubed inside a Grip Shifter with Finish Line teflon lube, and used that for a long time.

Now I disassembled everything, and the outer rubber part is quite stained and sticky.

I tried to brush the teflon aside with water and soap, and even a mild degreaser, but since teflon is not exactely grease, I just spread the stains even more.

So, question is: Which substance / method should I use to clean that?

Comment: Teflon lubes use a volatile carrier to deliver the teflon.  Not sure what it is but it's a quickly evaporating liquid, most likely petroleum based.  So in all likelihood that carrier penetrated the rubber, making the stains impossible to remove.

Comment: You mean the outer grip portion of the shifting mechanism is turning sticky?

Comment: The teflon lube, as soon as applied months ago, evaporated and left the characteristic wax-like teflon coating inside the working surface of the shifter. But with use, the edge of the shifter was a bit sticky, since some lube was coming out. When I disassembled and started cleaning, the brushing just spread the wax-like, somewhat dirty teflon over the rubber surface. The rubber itself seems fine, but it's dirty with teflon. It's not impossible, though, that it penetrated the rubber a bit, but I would like to try to clean it with a proper method so that I can know.

Comment: Unfortunately, you need to be careful with solvents on rubber and plastic parts.  I'd maybe try silicone spray lube, figuring it may use a similar vehicle to the Teflon.

Comment: @DanielRHicks Gonna try some silicone spray this weekend and post some feedback, thanks!

Comment: @DanielRHicks The teflon lube I've seen used an alcohol-based 'vehicle'. Although alcohol is a solvent, perhaps it doesn't dissolve teflon (perhaps it's a teflon suspension, not a teflon solution), and the alcohol's purpose as a 'vehicle' is simply to evaporate easily. Nevertheless, alcohol is something else that you could try (which might not dissolve rubber or plastic).

Comment: Yeah, standard ethyl, methyl, or isopropyl alcohol should be safe on rubber and plastic.

Comment: (I think a slightly sticky substance is included with the teflon to make it stick to the parts, and it's that sticky substance you need to dissolve.)

Comment: Some of the teflon sprays I've used (not on bikes) just use butane as a carrier, it evaporates almost instantly, but I don't know what it would do to the plastic in those few seconds.

Answer (score 3):

Try Dawn Dish soap its a little bit of scrubbing but it seems to work the best, its chem resistant so everything I have tried only makes it more sticky but dish soap hot water and work gets rid of it the best.  Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend an all-purpose cleaner like GooGone or Oops, but try it on a small spot first as it may remove the finish on whatever you're cleaning. Other than that, you can use a more abrasive cleaning utensil (pad, brush, towel, etc.) to scrape the congealed teflon off.

Answer (score 1):

I used a spray can of carburetor cleaner and it came right off. Then I put Dawn dishwashing soap on it and rinse clean.

Comment: One must be careful with carburetor cleaner as it is pretty strong. It can do damage to rubber/plastic parts if overused. So advise using sparingly, and only if lower-strength cleaners fail first.